# Go program exits after a connection refused

Tags: go, net-http

I'm Sending get requests to websites and get the statuscodes inside a loop, when the loop sends get request to a non-exist website, it breaks the program.

go version go1.12.6 darwin/amd64

```
func getRequest(url string) int {

    http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    return resp.StatusCode
} 

func checker(info []accountinfo) {
    var request string
    var statusCode int

    for i := range info {
        request = fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/", info[i].domain)
        statusCode = getRequest(request)
        if statusCode == 200 {
            fmt.Println("That's ok")
        } else {
            fmt.Println(info[i].domain, "not found or content is not valid")
        }

    }
}
```

I expect it print "something.com not found or content is not valid".
But it throws the error below.

```
2019/09/05 17:19:43 Get https://something.com/: dial tcp ip:443: connect: connection refused
exit status 1
```

**EDIT**

Using Println instead of Fatalln gives another error:

```
2019/09/05 17:52:18 Get https://something.com/: dial tcp ip:443: connect: connection refused
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x40 pc=0x124eebf]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.getRequest(0xc0000ae0e0, 0x1a, 0x0)
    /Users/ozan/monitoring-development/v2/main.go:147 +0xff
main.checker(0xc000584000, 0x8d, 0x100)
    /Users/ozan/monitoring-development/v2/main.go:110 +0xd3
main.main()
    /Users/ozan/monitoring-development/v2/main.go:67 +0x4dd
exit status 2
```

Comment: "Using Println instead of Fatalln gives another error" - of course. The request didn't complete successfully. You can't use `resp` in this case.

Comment: To make the program continue, do i have to make that request completed? How should i handle this error?

Comment: Printing an error alone is not "handling" it. You can't use `resp` if it's not valid. You're also doing a `GET` but not reading the response, which may be preventing you from reusing connections.

Answer (score 3):

`log.Fatalln`, as its name implies and [documentation clearly states](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Fatalln), prints the error and exits the program. If you don't want to exit, use `log.Println` instead.

Your logic for the "not found or not valid" error is based on status codes, but in order to get a status code, the request must complete. A request cannot complete to a host that doesn't exist or refuses connections. So you need to consider two types of "failure" cases:

1. A transport-level error, like DNS failure, connection refused/timed out, etc.
2. A protocol-level error, like HTTP status 500, etc.

Also note that you're treating *only* status 200 as success; this may be what's intended, it may not, as the entire 2xx block of status codes are success codes (e.g. 204 No Content is a common success response).

You likely want something like this:

```
resp, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err) // Assuming you want to see what the error actually was
    return -1    // Not perfect, but at least the caller will treat it as a "non-success" status code and give your expected result
}
```

A better implementation would be to return the status code and an error and handle both correctly in `checker`.